# How to addeventlistener to special selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touchmove

H1 guys, i want to ask for help solve my problem. So what i have:

**After click i have Sliding PANEL from left to right**

i Want while click add event listener to this panel, and if user **TOUCHMOVE** i want to close panel. (if someone can help to catch the direction (i mean from right to left) it will be amazing!)

What i tried:

```
$("#leftpanelshadow").addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CloseLeft();
  }, false);
```

! document.addEventLister is not a solution, because it always call this after touchmoving

```
e.preventDefault();
        CloseLeft();
```

P.S.
I'm writing this for mobile version of website

**CHECKED FOR DETECTING SWIPE IF SOMEONE NEED:**

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml

Comment: Use `.on` instead of `.addEventListener`

Comment: you can know the direction by watching the coordinate movement of the screen.

Comment: Perfect! it helped! But can you help to check direction of touchmove? or maybe there is another ways to check? i'd like to "make something" while touchmove from right to left, lenght of gesture maybe 100 pix? Or something like that? I'm doing it at first time.

Comment: Keep values of `x-y` co-ordinate on `touchstart` and compare values of `touchmove/touchend` with stored values.. Makes sense ?

Comment: Thx allot for all:) found ready function for swipes. edited post. if someone need check it out